# How can we add Google Pay or Apple pay in stripe hosted checkout page?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, checkout, google-pay, stripe-payments-js

As per this link https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout. It says that google Pay and Apple pay are build in feature of stripe hosted checkout page. Then they are not showing up in the checkout page. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGQc9.jpg)

can anyone tell me how to have them show up in the stripe hosted checkout page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Google Pay and Apple Pay are available using the hosted [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout) payment form.  However you do need to configure your Stripe Account to accept these payment methods.

You can configure this in your [account settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/payment_methods) under the Wallets section.

Comment: Thanks it has helped me a lot .. would you mind helping me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72573177/how-to-make-payment-method-set-as-default-in-stripe-after-one-time-checkout-paym

Comment: Mine already says "on", but it's still not showing up on the website.

Comment: Worth noting, if automatic tax collection is turned on (automatic_tax [enabled]) in the API call, then the Apple Pay and Google Pay will not show up. Unless you add a shipping field and make it required. Source: https://stripe.com/docs/tax/faq#are-apple-pay-and-google-pay-available-to-use-with-stripe-tax