# How to make Payment Method set as default in stripe after one time checkout payment

Tags: stripe-payments, checkout, payment-method

[Payment Method of a customer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DQPW.jpg) After checkout the payment method gets saved in the customer dashboard. How to make that Payment method set as default using API calls or is there any way to make it default at the first place when there is a successful checkout of one time payment.  [Want to make it like this with API calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGdgY.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could listen to the `checkout.session.completed`[1] event in your webhooks[2]. Once you get that object you could retrieve the Payment Intent [3] and use the `charges.data[0].payment_method` [4] to update[5] the customer’s default payment method[6].

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/retrieve

[4] https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-payment_method

[5] https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update

[6] https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method