# Google Pay Error: API Unable to download payment manifest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-pay

When I load my website I get this error:
Unable to download payment manifest "https://pay.google.com/about/".

This errors shows up indefinitely and eventually crashes the website. It happened when I developed my own code using the Docs. It happened also when I took the code straight from the NPM Docs. I cant figure it out.

This is the code that I am using.

```
import React from 'react';
import GooglePayButton from '@google-pay/button-react';

function GooglePay(props) {


    return (
        <GooglePayButton
            environment='TEST'
            paymentRequest={{
                apiVersion: 2,
                apiVersionMinor: 0,
                allowedPaymentMethods: [
                    {
                        type: 'CARD',
                        parameters: { 
                            allowedAuthMethods: ['PAN_ONLY', 'CRYPTOGRAM_3DS'],
                            allowedCardNetworks: ['AMEX', 'DISCOVER', 'MASTERCARD', 'VISA']
                        },
                        tokenizationSpecification: {
                            type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
                            parameters: {
                                gateway: 'example',
                                gatewyMerchantId: 'examleMerchantId',
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
                merchantInfo: {
                    merchantId: '12345678901234567890',
                    merchantName: 'Demo',
                },
                transactionInfo: {
                    totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
                    totalPriceLabel: 'Total',
                    totalPrice: props.totalAmount.toString(),
                    currencyCode: 'USD',
                    countryCode: 'US',
                },
                shippingAddressRequired: true,
                callbackIntents: ['PAYMENT_AUTHORIZATION'],
            }}
            onLoadPaymentData={paymentRequest => {
                console.log('Success', paymentRequest)
            }}
            onPaymentAuthorized={paymentData => {
                console.log('Payment Authorized Success', paymentData)
                return { transactionState: 'SUCCESS' }
            }}
            existingPaymentMethodRequired='false'
            buttonColor='black'
            buttonType='Buy'
        />
    )

};

export default GooglePay;
```

I am expecting Google Pay to work every time I click on it. Instead it may work the first time (may not) and then becomes un-clickable on the next re-load.

Comment: Does the button work for you here: https://google-pay-react.stackblitz.io Also, the "Unable to download payment manifest" console error is a chrome bug and should not affect your Google Pay integration. See here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1405229

Answer (score 3):

Be sure that:

1. Your stripe dashboard the google pay is enabled
2. Check if you have a real card added to your google wallet
3. Check if have added a real card in Chrome Browser Payment methods
4. Check if have added the real card in http://pay.google.com

Some updates from Stripe Team Support

> Thanks! Upon checking our resources, for using Google Pay on Stripe
> checkout you just need to have it enabled on your Dashboard payment
> methods:
>
> https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/payment_methods
>
> But, to test your integration for Google Pay, you’ll need to fulfill
> specific browser requirements for Chrome. When testing Google Pay you
> should have a *real* card saved in your Chrome browser or Google
> Wallet, and have your test API keys/test Google Pay environment
> active. The real card does not get charged, and Google passes a test
> card during the checkout flow instead of a real card. Our normal test
> cards do not work with Google Pay when the user tries to save them in
> Chrome.
>
> Chrome
>
> 1. Chrome 61 or newer
> 2. A saved payment card
>
> Chrome Mobile for Android
>
> 1. Chrome 61 or newer
> 2. An activated Google Pay card or a saved card
>
> When using Google Pay, including Android Pay, with a test mode key,
> you might see an “Unrecognized app” warning. This is expected and
> doesn’t show up in live mode.

Comment: Facing the same problem here, and I've checked all of the requirements above. Still I can't see the Google Pay button

Comment: @phrfpeixoto try disabling **automatic_tax** while calling API. It was issue for me on Stripe Checkout(Stripe hosted page). Check last comment on the answer for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72454383/how-can-we-add-google-pay-or-apple-pay-in-stripe-hosted-checkout-page

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have moved away from that project, so I can't validate it.
I've +1'ed your answer, and maybe that will help other weary travelers who stop by