# Bug with google pay button by Stripe

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js, stripe-payments, google-pay

when i use **Payment Request Button** cho my website(nuxtjs, stripe), with **google pay button**.
This button work for me but some people has a bug in console:

```
Unable to download payment manifest "https://pay.google.com/about/".
```

and they cant see this button.

Please help me resovle it

```
mounted() {
  const elements = stripe.elements();
  const prButton = elements.create('paymentRequestButton', {
    paymentRequest,
  });

  (async () => {
    // Check the availability of the Payment Request API first.
    const result = await paymentRequest.canMakePayment();
    console.log(result);
    if (result) {
      prButton.mount('#payment-request-button');
    } else {
      document.getElementById('payment-request-button').style.display = 'none';
    }
  })();
}
```

this code log null for bug case.

I spend 4 hours in internet and cant find anything to fix it

Comment: Can you share the code how you get the `result`? If Google Pay button doesn't show, it's also likely the customer doesn't have a saved payment method in his/her Google wallet. Google Pay button will only be shown if these [requirements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button?client=html#html-js-testing) are fulfilled.

Comment: put code, readable, **in the question**

Comment: anything in [this question which came up in a search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74995699/google-pay-error-api-unable-to-download-payment-manifest) help you

Comment: "Unable to download payment manifest" should not affect the button. It is a Chrome Bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1405229